# Custom launcher in Ubuntu 12.04 xdg/autostart

Tags: autostart, .desktop, xdg

I have some script that should start when user logs in. I've created .desktop file and put it into /etc/xdg/autostart. It works on two pretty old PCs with Ubuntu with a long life (10.xx -> 11.10 -> 12.04 at the moment), and doesn't work on freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04. `.desktop` file works correctly - it starts what I want when I double click it.

Here it is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/proxyauth.sh
Icon=utilities-terminal
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=true
NoDisplay=false
Name=Proxy Authentication
Comment=Use the command line
```

Is there any way I can debug or track what happens on login?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure Ubuntu has a way to add startup shell scripts; at least KDE (I use Kubuntu) has it.

Comment: What does this script? How did you call it? The name has to end in `.desktop`.

Comment: It configures proxy for the user, it's a long story with the corporate windows-proxy... Nothing special, just write config file and start cntlm daemon.
I've recently found out, that those two PCs don't start the script from time to time too :-/ I've changed nothing.
The file has .desktop extension.